# Как расширять меню и поле для ввода вместе с окном в PyQt 6?

Tags: python, qlayout, pyqt6, qtextedit, qmainwindow

Сейчас работаю с *PyQt6*. В окне имеется меню и поле для ввода текста. 
Нужно сделать так, чтобы меню и поле расширялись вместе с окном.

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QMenu, QToolBar, QAction, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout

class Window(QMainWindow):
    """MainWindow."""
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        """Initializer."""
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Python Menus&amp; Toolbars")
        self.resize(400,200)
        #self.centralWidget=QLabel("Hello,World")
        #self.centralWidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        #text = QTextEdit()
        #text.move(20, 20)
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self._createActions()
        self._createMenuBar()

    def _createMenuBar(self):
        text = QTextEdit(self)
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = QMenu("&File",self)
        menuBar.addMenu(fileMenu)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)
        editMenu=menuBar.addMenu("&Edit")
        editMenu.addAction(self.copyAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.pasteAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.cutAction)
        helpMenu=menuBar.addMenu("&Help")
        helpMenu.addAction(self.helpContentAction)
        helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutAction)

    '''
    def _createToolBars(self):
        fileToolBar = self.addToolBar("File")
        editToolBar=QToolBar("Edit",self)
        self.addToolBar(editToolBar)
        helpToolBar=QToolBar("Help",self)
        self.addToolBar(Qt.LeftToolBarArea,helpToolBar)
    '''
    def _createActions(self):
        self.newAction=QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("New")
        self.openAction=QAction("Open",self)
        self.saveAction=QAction("Save",self)
        self.exitAction=QAction("Exit",self)
        self.copyAction=QAction("&Copy",self)
        self.pasteAction=QAction("&Paste",self)
        self.cutAction=QAction("Cut",self)
        self.helpContentAction=QAction("Help",self)
        self.aboutAction=QAction("About",self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Fahhov, пожалуйста, лучше расскажите что вы хотите получить при изменении размера окна. Попробуйте как-то показать на изображении как должно выглядеть то, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Nick, фото врядли смогу показать. Но я хочу, чтобы при растягивании самого окна, строка ввода растягивалась вместе с ним

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте виджеты в менеджер компоновки.

```
import sys
'''               Установите свои импорты
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, \
    QMenu, QToolBar, QAction, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Python Menus&amp;")
        self.resize(400, 200)
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(objectName='centralWidget')
        self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet("""
            #centralWidget {
                background-color: rgb(96, 255, 128);
            }
        """)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.label = QLabel("Hello, QLabel")
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(253, 253, 253); background-color: #105652;")
        
        self.text = QTextEdit("Hello, QTextEdit")
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.text, 5)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1)

        self._createActions()
        self._createMenuBar()

    def _createMenuBar(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = QMenu("&File",self)
        menuBar.addMenu(fileMenu)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)
        editMenu=menuBar.addMenu("&Edit")
        editMenu.addAction(self.copyAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.pasteAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.cutAction)
        helpMenu=menuBar.addMenu("&Help")
        helpMenu.addAction(self.helpContentAction)
        helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutAction)

    def _createActions(self):
        self.newAction = QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("New")
        self.openAction = QAction("Open", self)
        self.saveAction = QAction("Save", self)
        self.exitAction = QAction("Exit", self)
        self.copyAction = QAction("&Copy", self)
        self.pasteAction = QAction("&Paste", self)
        self.cutAction = QAction("Cut", self)
        self.helpContentAction = QAction("Help", self)
        self.aboutAction = QAction("About", self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 10, QFont.Bold))
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]